# pandas groupby with length of lists

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need display in dataframe columns both the user_id and length of content_id which is a list object. But struggling to do using groupby.
Please help in both groupby as well as my question asked at the bottom of this post (how do I get the results along with user_id in dataframe?)

**Dataframe types:**

```
df.dtypes
```

**output:**

```
user_id       object
content_id    object
dtype: object
```

**Sample Data:**

```
    user_id     content_id
0   user_18085  [cont_2598_4_4, cont_2738_2_49, cont_4482_2_19...
1   user_16044  [cont_2738_2_49, cont_4482_2_19, cont_4994_18_...
2   user_13110  [cont_2598_4_4, cont_2738_2_49, cont_4482_2_19...
3   user_18909  [cont_3170_2_28]
4   user_15509  [cont_2598_4_4, cont_2738_2_49, cont_4482_2_19...
```

**Pandas query:**

```
df.groupby('user_id')['content_id'].count().reset_index()

df.groupby(['user_id'])['content_id'].apply(lambda x: get_count(x))
```

**output:**

```
    user_id     content_id
0   user_10013  1
1   user_10034  1
2   user_10042  1
```

When I tried without grouping, I am getting fine as below -

```
df['content_id'].apply(lambda x: len(x))


0       11
1        9
2       11
3        1
```

But, how do I get the results along with user_id in dataframe? Like I want in below format -

```
user_id   content_id
some xxx  11
some yyy  6
```

Comment: I don't see the problem. Just reassign your data back to your data frame and then call the appropriate columns. If there are duplicates, then do your groupby-sums.

Comment: But the groupby pandas query I have used above, are they correct? And also, for my last question I need help. I want to display user_id along with content_id which displays len of each list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.Groupby` returns a grouper element not the contents of each cell. As such it is not possible (without alot of workarounding) to do what you want. Instead you need to simply rewrite the columns (as suggested by @ifly6)

Using

```
df_agg = df.copy()
df_agg.content_id = df_agg.content_id.apply(len)
df_agg = df_agg.groupby('user_id').sum()
```

will result in the same dataframe as the `Groupby` you described.

For completeness sake the instruction for a single groupby would be

```
df.groupby('user_id').agg(lambda x: x.apply(len).sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

try converting content_id to a string, split it by comma, then reassemble as a list of lists then count the list items.

```
data="""index  user_id     content_id
0   user_18085  [cont_2598_4_4,cont_2738_2_49,cont_4482_2_19]
1   user_16044  [cont_2738_2_49,cont_4482_2_19,cont_4994_18_]
2   user_13110  [cont_2598_4_4,cont_2738_2_49,cont_4482_2_19]
3   user_18909  [cont_3170_2_28]
4   user_15509  [cont_2598_4_4,cont_2738_2_49,cont_4482_2_19]
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')

def convert_to_list(x):
    x=re.sub(r'[\[\]]', '', x)
    lst=list(x.split(','))
    return lst

df['content_id2']= [list() for x in range(len(df.index))]
for key,item in df.iterrows():
    lst=convert_to_list(str(item['content_id']))
    for item in lst:
        df.loc[key,'content_id2'].append(item)
    
def count_items(x):
    return len(x)

df['count'] = df['content_id2'].apply(count_items)
df.drop(['content_id'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'content_id2':'content_id'},inplace=True)
print(df)
```

output:

```
 index     user_id                                       content_id  count
0      0  user_18085  [cont_2598_4_4, cont_2738_2_49, cont_4482_2_19]      3
1      1  user_16044  [cont_2738_2_49, cont_4482_2_19, cont_4994_18_]      3
2      2  user_13110  [cont_2598_4_4, cont_2738_2_49, cont_4482_2_19]      3
3      3  user_18909                                 [cont_3170_2_28]      1
4      4  user_15509  [cont_2598_4_4, cont_2738_2_49, cont_4482_2_19]      3
​
```